# shell script: if statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm following the tutorial here: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/If..else..fi#Number_Testing_Script

My script looks like:

```
lines=`wc -l $var/customize/script.php`
if test $lines -le 10
then
    echo "script has less than 10 lines"
else
    echo "script has more than 10 lines"
fi
```

but my output looks like:

```
./boot.sh: line 33: test: too many arguments
script has more than 10 lines
```

Why does it say I have too many arguments? I fail to see how my script is different from the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you the first line #!/bin/bash in your script?      Also are you running the script in bash shell or ksh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wc -l file` command will print two words. Try this:

```
lines=`wc -l file | awk '{print $1}'`
```

---

To debug a bash script (boot.sh), you can:

```
$ bash -x ./boot.sh
```

It'll print every line executed.

Comment: @KevinDuke you should add a line `echo lines contains $lines` so you can see what's going on...

Comment: One way to help you in these cases is by using the -x option:

    "sh -x ./script_name"

This prints out the script with the variable values substituted.

Comment: `wc -l < file` will return only one word, though it needs to be trimmed.

Comment: `awk 'END{print NR}' file` will also count lines.

Answer (score 8):

```
wc -l file
```

outputs

```
1234 file
```

use

```
lines=`wc -l < file`
```

to get just the number of lines. Also, some people prefer this notation instead of backticks:

```
lines=$(wc -l < file)
```

Also, since we don't know if `$var` contains spaces, and if the file exists:

```
fn="$var/customize/script.php"
if test ! -f "$fn"
then
    echo file not found: $fn
elif test $(wc -l < "$fn") -le 10
then
    echo less than 11 lines
else
    echo more than 10 lines
fi
```

Comment: This will produce unexpected output if the script has permission issues, or some other error occurs.  Probably better to just run `wc` and abort if it fails, allowing `wc` to print an appropriate error message (which belongs on stderr).  For example: `a=$( wc -l < "$fn" ) || exit 1; if test "$a" -le 10; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should use

```
if [[ $lines -gt 10 ]]; then
    something
else
  something
fi
```

`test condition` is really outdated, and so is it's immediate successor, `[ condition ]`, mainly because you have to be really careful with those forms. For example, you must quote any `$var` you pass to `test` or `[ ]`, and there are other details that get hairy. (tests are treated in every way as any other command). Check out this [article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#pitfalls_summarized) for some details.

Comment: In Bash, for integer comparisons, you should use `if (( lines < 10 ))`. The comparison you are showing is a lexical comparison which will fail for `$lines` with a value of `2`, for example.

Comment: `test` and `[` are not outdated, just highly abused.  But they are much more portable than `[[` and `((`.